# Is 'Blood libel' an established expression?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I came across the word, 'Blood libel,' apparently associated with Ms. Sarah
 Palin's agressive statement which was zeroed in at Democratic lowmakers in today's  Washington Post.
Neither Concise Oxford Dictionary nor Oxford American Dictionary  carries this word. The latter defines 'libel' as:

1. Published falese statement that damages a person's reputation.
2. A statement or anything that brings discredit on a person or thing.

Both of which doesn't seem to me fitting to 'Blood libel' used in the context of the above statements. I think I can guess what the word means here, but is 'Blood libel' a broadly received expression in U.S. and U.K? Who coined this word on the earth?
I'm asking this because it's in many cases shown in parentheses.

Quotes:

> Questions about whether Palin knew what she was getting into by using "**blood libel**" miss the mark. Right now, she is as much provocateur as politician.

And:

> Within hours of a tragedy unfolding, journalists and pundits should not manufacture a **blood libel** that serves only to incite the very hatred and violence they purport to condemn. That is reprehensible.

Comment: You’re misquoting her: She said “pundints”, not “pundits”.

Comment: Konrad. I simply pasted the second quote from an excerpt I found in i-google. I didn't know she demonstrated the fame of malapropist in the above instance. - Yoichi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Blood libels](http://www.reference.com/browse/blood%20libel?__utma=1.2086776073.1294906748.1294906748.1294906748.1&__utmb=1.2.10.1294906748&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1294906750.1.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=%28organic%29|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=dictionary%20%22blood%20libel%22&__utmv=-&__utmk=252675081) seems to be an established expression, one used without quotes (`"`) nor parenthesis.

It is employed as such in this article "[Sarah Palin causes a controversy with the phrase “blood libel.” What does it mean, and why are people upset?](http://hotword.dictionary.com/sarah-palin-blood-libel/)".
[Benjol](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/529/benjol) also mentions the [BBC article "What does 'blood libel' mean?"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-12176503).

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_libel) details its long history.

Comment: Vonc. Thanks a lot for your quick input. The article on 'Blood libels' in the Wikipedia is really helpful and interesting. I had the slightest idea that the word has weathered a long path of history, and its origin dates back to 12th century when the blood libels  targtted at Jews took place. Though I'm not yet through the article because it's pretty long, I'll print it out after this, and peruse full contents by 'kicking back'(the usage I learned from the site). Again many thanks.- Yoich

Comment: @VonC, another link [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-12176503) to add to your list, though it's probably mostly pinched off Wikipedia :)

Comment: @Benjol: thank you for this link. I have included it in the answer.

Comment: @VonC, +1 then ;)

Comment: Sarah Palin's effort to defuse controversy backfires with 'blood libel' comment.

Comment: VonC. "Blood libel' seems to be parenthesized when it is refered to as a problematic comment from Sarah Palin like: "Sarah Palin's effort to defuse controversy backfires with 'blood libel' comment." - Yoichi

Comment: @Yoichi: I wouldn't see blood libel as parenthesized in that case (but this is just my interpretation). The simple quotes help to define the expression referenced by the comment.